# svcutil not exporting metadata for generic DataContract types

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, datacontract, svcutil.exe

Up until now I've been implementing WCF services out of the box by letting Visual Studio take care of generating all of the client-side proxy code. But to prevent some maintenance nightmares, I now need to share DataContracts between different services on the client side. So I've moved the DataContracts for my services into their own assembly so that I can generate a client-side assembly containing the DataContract classes as is demoed [here](http://www.freddes.se/2010/05/02/sharing-datacontracts-between-wcf-services/comment-page-1/#comment-8822) and [here](http://paxcel.net/blog/sharing-datacontract-across-wcf-services-without-distributing-separate-copies-to-the-client/).

After generating & referencing the client DataContract assembly and specifying Reuse Types when generating the proxy in Visual Studio, most of the DataContract code was gone from the generated Reference.cs class, except a couple types were left behind:

```
public partial class OWSResultOfArrayOfguid ...

public partial class OWSResultOfOrderFulfillmentResult ...
```

These are the return types of a couple service methods that use a DataContract with a generic type. Here is its declaration:

```
[DataContract(Name = "OWSResultOf{0}")]
public class OWSResult<T>
```

After inspecting the .xsd files that I generated using svcutil, OWSResult, of any type, does not appear to be included. Here is the command I used to generate the files:

```
>svcutil /dconly "C:\...\bin\Debug\OWS.DataContracts.dll"
```

Where DataContracts.dll is the assembly I moved all of the DataContract definitions into. And in case I'm just not seeing the definition in the .xsd files, here is the command I'm using to generate the C# client code:

```
>svcutil /dconly /language:C# *.xsd /out:OWS.DataContracts.cs /edb /s /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /r:C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
```

So I added a KnownType attribute to my generic DataContract (OWSResult) to tell the tool about these implementations of the type. EG:

```
[KnownType(typeof(OWSResult<Guid>))][KnownType(typeof(OWSResult<OrderFulfillmentResult>))]
```

but it still does not generate these types. How can I get svcutil to include these?